# iOS in-app purchase. Need clarification

Tags: iphone, ios

I am planning to use subscription (auto renew) type of in-app purchase. My idea is to allow one subscription per device. (i.e.) if someone purchase the subscription on iPhone, he shouldn't be able to use same subscription on iPad. Instead I want to force user to new subscription for other device. But from in-app purchase what i understood is that, if user subscribe for a particular item, if he tries to purchase the same thing again, app store allows to user to restore already purchased item.

As per my current setup, all the downloads will happen from a separate server and I am going to keep all the receipts and content in that server. In order to implement this particular thing, what should I do in my application? Could someone help me on this?

Also if I want to limit download of data from server using in-app purchase for only 3 device? Beyond 3 I want user to make payment via in-app purchase again? How will I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apple's [In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf) state that you *must* support restoring subscriptions to all of a user's devices (see page 7).

Also consider if your content is *episodic* (such as a TV show or magazine) because that's  a requirement for using auto-renewing subscriptions. For things like time-limited access to a certain feature, like voice guidance in a navigation app, you'd need to use non-renewing subscriptions.

Comment: Building off of this, if you must split the versions of your IAP, add a unique feature or two to either the iPad or iPhone version, and then create two available purchases.